# How to export a string to a file in HTML & Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I use the javascript below to save the data from the websql database to the consol.log, but how do I export it to a file? This is for Phonegap but hopefully also for a web version of the same page.
I hope someone has an idea what to do. Thanks

```
    function dbError(e) {
        console.log("SQL ERROR");
        console.dir(e);
    }

    function backup(table) {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    curatio.webdb.db.readTransaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select * from "+table, [], function(tx,results) {
            var data = convertResults(results);
            console.dir(data);
            def.resolve(data);
        });
    }, dbError);

    return def;
}

$(document).on("click", "#doBackupBtn", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Begin backup process");

    $.when(
        backup("allergies")

    ).then(function(allergies, log) {
        console.log("All done");
        //Convert to JSON
        var data = {allergies:allergies};
        var serializedData = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(serializedData);
        (function(console){

console.save = function(data, filename){

    if(!data) {
        console.error('Console.save: No data')
        return;
    }

    if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

    if(typeof data === "object"){
        data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
    }

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
        e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a    = document.createElement('a')

    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)
 }
})(console)

    });

});

    //Generic utility
function convertResults(resultset) {
    var results = [];
    for(var i=0,len=resultset.rows.length;i<len;i++) {
        var row = resultset.rows.item(i);
        var result = {};
        for(var key in row) {
            result[key] = row[key];
        }
        results.push(result);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
function download(filename, content) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(content));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    pom.click();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
download("test.txt", "Success :)");
```

Comment: Hi ReeCube. Where and how do I use the 'Usage' ? Sorry, kinda new to javascript.

Comment: Depends on where you want to download the file, everywhere where you have an console.log?

Comment: Ahh.
It works great! I added it to just after })(console)
I guess I have to change the "Success :)" to somehow contain the data of the string? As currently all the file contains is Success :)

Comment: yes, the first parameter is the filename and the second one is the content of the file

Comment: YAY, If I change it to serializedData it works! Thanks for your help!